# strings in if statement

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I am trying to write a code which lists all words used in a text file without repeating. I succeeded to list all the words but I always get repeating ,the if statement line 17 always gives the value of 0.I have no idea why , the words are listed properly in the vector. Any suggestion ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class reading {
public:
    string word;
    vector<string> words;
};

int checkifexist(string word) {
    reading readingobject;
    bool exist = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < readingobject.words.size(); i++) {
        if (word == readingobject.words[i]) {
            exist = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return exist;
}

int main() {

    reading readingobject;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("Book.txt");

    if (inFile.fail()) {
        cout << "file didn't open" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    readingobject.word.resize(1);
    while (!inFile.eof()) {
        inFile >> readingobject.word;
        if (checkifexist(readingobject.word) == 1)
            continue;

        cout << readingobject.word << endl;
        readingobject.words.push_back(readingobject.word);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `reading readingobject;` creates a new object, whose `words` vector is empty

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/)

Comment: @UnholySheep ,I added another line readingobject.word.resize(1); ,but it doesn't work and the vector gets a resize every time in the while loop.

Comment: You are missing the point.  You are creating a 2nd `reading` object that you should not be creating in the first place, you need to get rid of it.

Comment: In `int checkifexist(string word) {` the `reading readingobject;` is a totally separate variable than the one with the same name in `int main()`. These variables are in different scopes. Instead `int checkifexist(string word)` should be a class member of the reading class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of `checkifexist()`, you are creating a new `reading` object, whose `words` vector is empty, so there is nothing for the loop to do, and the function returns 0.

You need to instead pass in the `reading` object from `main()` as an input parameter, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class reading {
public:
    vector<string> words;
};

bool checkifexist(const reading &readingobject, const string &word)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < readingobject.words.size(); ++i) {
        if (word == readingobject.words[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

    /* alternatively:
    return (std::find(readingobject.words.begin(), readingobject.words.end(), word) != readingobject.words.end());
    */
}

int main()
{
    reading readingobject;
    string word;

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("Book.txt");

    if (!inFile) {
        cout << "file didn't open" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    while (inFile >> word) {
        if (checkifexist(readingobject, word))
            continue;

        cout << word << endl;
        readingobject.words.push_back(word);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, when it comes to tracking unique elements, you can use a `std::set` instead of a `std::vector`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class reading {
public:
    set<string> words;
};

int main()
{
    reading readingobject;
    string word;

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("Book.txt");

    if (!inFile) {
        cout << "file didn't open" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    while (inFile >> word) {
        if (readingobject.words.insert(word).second)
            cout << word << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```